# Not able to create folder with image in android

Tags: java, android, file, sdk, android-sdcard

I'm trying to create a folder with an image file.

**here is code**

```
File folder = new    File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Aqeel/Images");
    folder.mkdirs();
    String extStorageDirectory = folder.toString();
    File file = new File(extStorageDirectory, "Image2.PNG");
    if(!folder.exists()){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Not Exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

**here is my manifest too**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.bernardo.hellow">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".hello"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

I've added the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission but it still does not working.

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? What do you think it should do, and what does it do instead?

Comment: @Bernardo D'Agostino your targetSdk?

Comment: You must be getting SecurityException, please check!

Comment: @Bernardo D'Agostino   Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38011181/3117966) if your targetSdk is 23